# Can somebody help me out with this Lex-Yacc parsing trouble?

Tags: yacc, lex

See that what I want is totally ignore `$display` kind of syntax in my parser. So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441674/in-lex-how-to-parse-some-code-until-a-special-symbol) so that I can parse `if(1) $display("Hello");` like `if(1) ;` which has no problem. But when there is only `$display("Hello");` without `if(1)`, my parser will generate a single `;`, which cause `syntax error`. Can anyone help me with this. It'd be appreciated.

---

The parser i'm current modifying don't parse `$display`, it shows `syntax error`. And my purpose is really simple: use the easiest way to ignore `$display("Hello");` without effect other syntax. And the situation is like in:

```
always @(*)
begin
if(1) $display("Hello");
end
```

If I treat `$display("Hello");` as `;`, the above codes will be parsed as:

```
always @(*)
begin
if(1) ;
end
```

It's okay for the parser, but if there are some code like this:

```
always @(*)
begin
$display("Hello");
end
```

It will be parsed as:

```
always @(*)
begin
;
end
```

which is not okay. So I'm stuck here. Please help.

Comment: Comments seem to have been removed here, or more probably your previous identical post has been deleted, but you're still going to have to post your .y and .l files if you want any help; your requirement to just ignore things when parsing is not implementable with these tools; and your question remains pretty unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I will look into it again, if I still can't figure it out, I will post my .l and .y files here and make my question more clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So without knowing your .y and .lex, I would just add rules to eat up

```
$display (...);
```

maybe like

```
display0 = Dollardisplay Leftbracket parameterlist Rightbracket {/* ignore it */}
display : display0 | display0 Semi
```

and then insert this `display`-rule where appropriate in your grammar

that means, the rule would optionally include the trailing `;` Of course by this you can introduce ambiguities and thus reduce reduce conflicts. Or you refactor your rules about statements and alow empty ones (a single `;`). But would be really easier to answer with having the grammar and the lexer...